# PHP script to create file if no exist

Tags: php

I have a small problem with my php code. Please take a look:

```html
<?php
$urlud = $json['url'];
$content = 'Content 1 if file no exist will generate';
$filename = $json['id'].".html";
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "File exists!";
} else {
    file_put_contents('dir1/'. $filename, $content, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
?>
<?php
$urlud = $json['url'];
$content = 'Content 2 if file no exist will generate';
$filename = $json['id'].".html";
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "File exists!";
} else {
    file_put_contents('dir2/'. $filename, $content, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
?>
```

This code will generate 2 files in different directories with different content. My problem is:

1. This code keeps replacing my old file content. Any solution to make it create only if the file doesn't exist ?
2. Any other input to make this code simpler?

Thanks.

Comment: simple, add counter with file name

Comment: maybe since you are writing to dir2 you ahould also be checking for the file there

Comment: another solution, use php randon string function and add it with file name so you will have `$filename $string` and `$string` will be unique everytime

Comment: i'm still unable to do that.. already change dir2 function to different call like $filename2 and still have same problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (file_exists('dir1/'. $filename))
```

and

```
if (file_exists('dir2/'. $filename))
```

You have to check the full path of the file not only the file name. E.g. imagine $filename to be "readme.txt" This file is probably not existing in your script path. And you expect it to be in dir1 or dir2.

Comment: hi @Harald Doderer, thanks for your solution.. this work like i want.. old file keep on there and not replacing with new one..